# regexp_replace to duplicate the substring in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

### Requirement

---

There is one requirement . The regexp_replace has to duplicate the sub string no.of times as ',,' is present.

`(,xyz,,12,).*` has to replace with `(,xyz,,12,).*(,xyz,,12,).*`

### Example:

```
    Input : (.*(,ELF,,NLF,).*)@(.*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,).*)

    Output : (.*(,ELF,,NLF,).*(,ELF,,NLF,).*)@(.*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,).*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,).*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,).*)
```

Please help . Can this be done using regexp_replace?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. Try this:

```
select regexp_replace('(.*(,ELF,,NLF,).*)@(.*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,).*)'
                     ,'(\.\*[A-Z,\(\)]+)\.\*\)@\((\.\*[A-Z,\(\)]+)\.\*\)'
                     ,'\1\1.*)@(\2\2\2.*)') 
from dual;
```

This do exactly what you posted as example.

Comment: Thank you kacper .. The input string is corrected now . it is not replacing as no.of times

Comment: (.*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,).*) need to replace as (.*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,).*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,).*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,).*)

Comment: @Bhaskar So you want first group twice and second three times?

Comment: Yes kacper . here  I am delimiting values with ',,' . The output has to be as that many times . For example  (.*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,,123,).*) need to replace as (.*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,,123).*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,,123,).*(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,,123,).*‌​(,ABC,,CDF,,SDE,,123,).*‌​) .. Thanks

Comment: Sorry kacper ..The input string is dynamic . It could be having any no.of fields separated by '@' . The values in the field are separated by ',,'               Input: (.*(,ELF,,NLF,).*)@(.*(,1,,3,).*)@(.*(,9999,).*)@(.*(,ORG,).*)@(.*(,N,).*)@(.*(,9999,).*)@(.*(,!Y,).*)@(.*(,CMM,).*))
 Output: (.*(,ELF,,NLF,).*(,ELF,,NLF,).*)@(.*(,1,,3,).*(,1,,3,).*)@(.*(,9999,).*)@(.*(,ORG,).*)@(.*(,N,).*)@(.*(,9999,).*)@(.*(,!Y,).*)@(.*(,CMM,).*))

Comment: @Bhaskar You asked a question I gave you an answer. Your example is multiplicating first string twice second three times. Now you're posting completely different example. What mre this is not coding service. Try to understand an answer and use it. Do not expect someone will do coding for you.

Comment: Sure Kacper .. Thank you for the help